# Start a new Clash of Clans account without logging in to the old one

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have TH9 village that is linked to my Note 8.0. I want to leave this village intact and create a new village on my new Galaxy S6. I have a new Gmail and Google+ account to link the new village to.

When I open Clash of Clans for the first time on the new device it asks me to login to my TH9 village. **What do I do to make my new device's village separate from my android tablet's village?**

Comment: Are you talking about a lvl 9 TH or Clan?

Comment: @Darakath even with that information what does that help for the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If the question comes up like this:

**Load village?**
Do you want to load Chief ____'s village with Town Hall level 9? Warning: progress in the current game will be lost.

Then simply tap the "Cancel" button when you open the game. If that is not the prompt that you are given, please specify more clearly (possibly provide screenshots) what exactly happens when you open Clash of Clans.

Comment: If you have already been asked to log in with your TH9 village and you did, there is no easy way to create a new village separate from your existing one.

Answer (score 1):

When it asks to load your TH9 village, say No. Then go into settings and Log In to Google+ with your new email.

Answer (score 0):

When you download Clash of Clans on your new device, log out of your Apple ID before you try to open it. Then open it (when logged out of your Apple ID) and start a new village. After you have made some small progress on your village, try to log back in to your Apple ID. Then when you open up Clash of Clans again on your device, it *should* have separated from your other account.

Comment: Apple ID on an Android device ^^